General form of Jacobi Theta Transformation $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} e^{n^2 \pi / x} = \sqrt{x} \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} e^{n^2 \pi x} $
I was looking into the functional equation of $\zeta(s)$ and at one point the proof uses the Jacobi Theta Transformation:

$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} e^{n^2 \pi / x} = \sqrt{x} \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} e^{n^2 \pi x} $$

I was wondering if there are more identities like this for series such as

$\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} a(n) e^{-n^2 \pi x}$ where $a(n)$ is an arithmetic function with some conditions.

I tried to look it up with Jacobi theta transformation general form and other combinations of words, but could not find any sources. If is highly appreciated if someone can kindly refer me to possible literature or resource.

The functional equation listed comes from the Poisson summation formula; the main idea is that $e^{-\pi t^2}$ is, up to a constant, its own Fourier transform. You can experiment with different summands and get similar results.
The most relevant generalization, though, is probably modular forms: well-behaved complex functions $f(z)$ for $\Im z > 0$ that satisfy a functional equation of the form
\begin{align*}
f\left(\frac{az + b}{cz + d}\right) &= (cz + d)^k f(z) & \text{for all} \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}&\in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})
\end{align*}
for some fixed $k$ (called the weight of $f$). In particular, $f(z + 1) = f(z)$ and $f(-1/z) = z^k f(z)$. (In fact, the matrices corresponding to $z \to z + 1$ and $z \to -1/z$ generate $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, so this condition is sufficient; we can look at the same relations for other subgroups $\Gamma\subset SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ as well, though.) I'm being vague about what "well-behaved" means here, but one of the properties we want is for the Fourier series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n e^{2\pi i n z}$ of $f$ to converge to $f$. The theta series is thus almost a modular form of weight $1/2$ ("almost" because of some complications with the square root). It turns out that the Eisenstein series
\begin{align*}
E_k(z) &= 1 + \alpha_k \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sigma_{k - 1}(n)e^{2\pi i n z}
\end{align*}
are modular forms of weight $k$ for $k = 4, 6, 8, \dots$, where the $\alpha_k$ are certain constants and $\sigma_{k-1}(n) = \sum_{d|n} d^{k-1}$ is the divisor function. This is the simplest incarnation of the idea (and it's already not very simple), but there are many variants of it that produce other arithmetic functions to work with.
